# Do Wireless Routers with a USB port for 3G/4G USB modem support normal file sharing?

Tags: router, wifi, network-share

I'm looking forward to buying a wireless router with a USB port, so that I can share my 1 TB external Hard Drive over Wi-Fi among my devices.

I came across one such router, [TP-Link 3G/4G Wireless N router TL-MR3420](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4691_TL-MR3420.html#overview).

The specifications say that it has a USB port for connecting a 3G/4G USB modem which is fine.
**But in case I connect an external hard drive or a pen drive to the router instead of a USB modem, will I able to share the drive contents over Wi-Fi, as routers with USB ports but no support for USB modems do?**

If yes, does it mean that all similar routers(with USB modem support) support file sharing too?

I know this is a basic question but I'm confused since no where on the site file sharing is mentioned and I'd like to know for sure before investing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the presence of a USB port does not automatically mean you can share files to your wifi network.

But that is highly dependent upon the device. If it's a feature, it would be advertised. Otherwise, don't assume this is possible.